# Access JavaScript "this" from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, alpacajs

I'm currently working with the AlpacaJS library within my typescript project. This JavaScript/JQuery library is included in my Typescript class and wants me to pass some options in a json style object like so:

```
this.options = {
    "collapsible": false,
    "fields": {
        "id": {
            "events": {
                "change": function () {
                    console.log(this.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Passing this object i say: add a change event to the field "id" within the form which alpaca generates. Using "this" within that function gives me the "this" of the library, and NOT the typescript class "this".

**The problem**: What if i like to call a method or variable within my Typescript class? I would have to use "this", but "this" is binded to the alpaca/javascript this. I can't change it to `(event) => { ... }` or `{ ...}.bind(this)` because that way i CAN access the typescript "this", but i CAN'T access the alpaca/javascript this, i need both of them....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i CAN'T access the alpaca/javascript this, i need both of them

Use the standard javascript trick of capturing `this` before creating the function:

```
let _self = this;
this.options = {
    "collapsible": false,
    "fields": {
        "id": {
            "events": {
                "change": function () {
                    console.log(_self.getValue());  // the class instance
                    console.log(this); // the lib version 
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This tip is documented here as well : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Using  `self` withtin typescript return an object of type `Window` ? It doesn't contain my Typescript methods/variables

Comment: I missed the line `let _self = this;` -.- I'm sorry. Looks like this is working! Going to test it out

Comment: Between, just wondering. Why CAN i access a `let` within this block scope but can't i access the other typescript variables/functions?

Comment: `can't i access the other typescript variables/functions?` : You can. Not sure what you mean

Comment: using the _self i CAN access the other typescript class variables/functions.  But without that _self i can't. So why can't i, but can i access the _self?

Comment: `So why can't i, but can i access the _self` There is only one thing that  the *effectively a variable* `this` can be bound to. If you use a fat arrow it is bound to the lexical scope (in your case the class instance). Without it it is a choice on *who calls the function* (the library in this case). Since you want *two things* you need to use *two variables*. In your case one is `this` (from the lib) and the other is `_self` (bound to the class instance)

Comment: I've added this tip here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html